# NSURLConnection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge persistence

Tags: ios, ssl, tls1.2

The (soon to be deprecated) NSURLConnectionDelegate allows you to handle a TLS trust challenge like so:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
        [challenge.sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Assuming that the same x509 certificate is being presented by the same server, my testing shows that the effect of this method is cached for the duration of the application execution. This method is not hit again.

Is there a way to force the application to forget the effect of this method after the handling has occurred, such that subsequent hits to the same web service force this method to be called?

Comment: Did you get any workaround for this issue? I'm facing the same and this delegate isn't getting called on successive calls to same web service even after killing/terminating the app and relaunching.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Since NSURLConnection is being deprecated, I have since updated everything to NSURLSession. NSURLSession does not cache answers, so this is no longer an issue for me. There were only a few small issues with the migration. Otherwise it was surprisingly pain free.

Comment: Thanks for your response. OK, I'll also try changing NSURLConnection to NSURLSession.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm using [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:...].

Comment: Or rejectProtectionSpaceAndContinueWithChallenge:.

Comment: Neither of those work. The idea is to not cancel the authentication challenge. It should be handled properly, but handled every time there is a challenge.